# SQL select all logged in users from today

Tags: mysql

How I can select all logged in users today? I have two tables one holding users information and another holding all login/logout time info.

```
table users
===================================
userid | Name | FamilyName | Position

table movements
===================================
userid | Date | Hour | Status 

Table movements fields:

userid - holds user unique ID number (same as table users);
Date - holds users login/logout date (example: 2013-10-08 00:00:00);
Hour - holds users login/logout date time (example: 2013-10-08: 17:10:39);
Status - holds users flag (0 or 1) where 1 - login and 0 - logout;
```

Table users are self explanatory.

I've been trying something like this so far:

```
select p.userid, 
       p.Name, 
       p.FamilyName, 
       p.Position, 
       m.Date, 
       m.Status, 
       m.Hour 
from users as p 
   INNER JOIN movements as m ON p.userid=m.userid;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that all users who have logged in today, or all users still logged in today?

Comment: It is all users still logged in + their personal info as Name, FamilyName and Position from the first table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Okay given your other comments, what is in the date and hour columns? You question says they are both dates, which doesn't make sense. And why do you need max hour anyway. Still logged in means the last movement is a login, so it's got to be max hasn't it?

Comment: Sorry, the Hour field holds time bit as well, I've just edited my question. I need max hour because first because I am using the query for showing currently logged in users and second because the user may login and logout a few time per day. Each login or logout is a new row insert, the table movements holds all the user login logout history.

Comment: @StoyanBukovich That still doesn't really explain the need for the 'hour' column. Aren't they both of type date/time? Wouldn't it contain the same data as the 'date' column? Does your code somehow split the current date and time into two fields?

Comment: one column is holding only date, year and month info, the other column is holding date, year, month, hour, minutes, seconds. It looks strange but I haven't did the DB architecture, unfortunately it is inherited project, and now its on late stage to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for explanation in comments:**

For anyone currently logged in:

```
Select 
   u.userid, 
   u.Name, 
   u.FamilyName, 
   u.Position,
   m.Date,
   m.Hour
From
   users u 
      Inner Join (
         Select m1.*
         From movements m1
            Left Outer Join movements m2 on ( m1.userid = m2.userid AND m1.Hour < m2.Hour )
         Where 
            m2.UserId Is NULL and
            m1.Date >= CurDate() ) m on m.userid = u.userid
Where m.Status = 1
```

Comment: How can I get the last login time (max Hour records) only

Comment: The first query does not take logout into account.  If a user has logged in once that day, then they will be shown in the results regardless if they have already logged-off.

Comment: I answered before Stoyan's comment that elaborated upon the process and structure. I will revise after he clarifies the hours column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
    p.userid, p.Name, p.FamilyName, p.Position
from 
    users as p 
inner join 
    movements as m on p.userid=m.userid
where 
    day(m.date) = day(getdate()) and
    month(m.date) = month(getdate()) and
    year(m.date) = year(getdate())
```

*Note: you didn't specify which DB Server you're using.
getdate() is for Microsoft Sql Server. If you use MySql you have to use curdate().
If you use other DB servers you should search for an equivalent function.*

*In Sql Server getdate() stores date & time, so if you compare date with "=" they could be different if they have the same day but different times.*

Comment: The correct answer for a question *only* tagged `sql` would be to use the functions defined by the SQL standard: `current_date` and `extract()`

Comment: I am using MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. Hour is a DATETIME field that contains a timestamp of the login/logout event
2. Dates in the database are in local time, and when you say "logged in users today" you are referring to today in local time.
3. The time on the server is also in local time.
4. status cannot be any value other than 1 or 0

> ```
> select p.Name, 
>        p.FamilyName, 
>        p.Position,  
>        MAX(m.Hour) logged_in_datetime
> FROM users AS p,
>      movements as m
> WHERE p.userid = m.userid
>   AND m.Hour >= DATE(NOW())
> GROUP BY p.Name, 
>        p.FamilyName, 
>        p.Position
> HAVING SUM( IF(m.status=1,1,-1)) > 0
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The following query will give you the userids of active users of the current date, you should be able to figure the rest out from there...

```
select distinct(userid) from movements where date = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Care to elaborate Tony?

Comment: Saw it before your edit when it was Select * From Select distinct....), well at least that how it appeared on my tv thingy.

Comment: Ps I didn't and still haven't downvoted. If I had I would have said so, more to the point I'd have said why....